# Javascript Class Instantiation

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I've created a simple javascript class to wrap [slick carousel](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/).

**What is the best way to instantiate multiple instances of this class?**

I've currently got the below, which search the DOM and creates a new class instance of the component, if found. I suspect my project will grow a little and this 'root' file may because a little bloated/confusing. Is there a better way to organize it?

I'm going to be adding additional classes for further functionality, so trying to find the best approach early.

**main.js**

```
import Carousel from '../app/assets/javascripts/carousel/Carousel';

var carouselElements = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('slick-media'));  
  if (carouselElements) {
    carouselElements.map(function (element) {
      new Carousel(element, true, {xs: 6, md: 6, lg: 6 });
    });
  }
```

**Carousel.js**

```
export default class Carousel {
   constructor(element, variableWidth = false, breakpoint) {
      this.element = element;
      this.variableWidth = variableWidth;
      this.breakpoint = breakpoint

      this._init(element);

      /* Bind methods */
      this._init = this._init.bind(this);
   }

   _init() {
    this._instantiateSlick(this.element);
   }

   _instantiateSlick(element) {
    $(element).slick({
      lazyLoad: 'ondemand',
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      adaptiveHeight: true,
      useTransform: true,
      /* Default over lg breakpoint */
      slidesToShow: this.breakpoint.lg,
      /* Allow slick to calculate widths */
      variableWidth: this.variableWidth,
      responsive: [
        {
          breakpoint: 1199,
          settings: {
            slidesToShow: this.breakpoint.lg,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            infinite: true
          }
        },
        {
          breakpoint: 991,
          settings: {
            slidesToShow: this.breakpoint.md,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            infinite: true
          }
        },
        {
          breakpoint: 480,
          settings: {
            slidesToShow: this.breakpoint.xs,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            infinite: true
          }
        }]
    });
   }
}
```

Comment: This code seems to be perfectly valid and fine to me :)

Comment: Don't use `map` when you're not using the array it returns, it's pointless overhead. Use one of [the many other ways to loop through arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476).

Comment: Is your question about the first code block creating instances, or about the `Carousel` class?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - sorry should have made that clearer, it's about the main.js file, and the way it's instantiating multiple instances. Is this approach the best possible? Also, is it scalable in a big project, where there will be multiple classes, this file is going to become pretty unreadable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've clarified that your question is about how you're *using* your class (e.g., the code in `main.js`):

> it's about the main.js file, and the way it's instantiating multiple instances. Is this approach the best possible?

There are a couple of nits to pick:

1. You're using `map` to create an array you fill with `undefined` and never use. When you're not using the returned array, don't use `map`; use `forEach` of any of [several other ways to loop over arrays and array-like structures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476).
2. There's no need for the `if`; methods like `getElementsByClassName` always return a `NodeList` or `HTMLCollection` (depending on the method), even if it's empty.

> Also, is it scalable in a big project, where there will be multiple classes, this file is going to become pretty unreadable?

I don't see any reason for it to become unreadable. If you want to stick to `getElementsByClassName` (because it can be **amazingly** fast; note that it doesn't exist on obsolete browsers like IE8 though):

```
import Carousel from '../app/assets/javascripts/carousel/Carousel';

const forEach = Function.call.bind(Array.prototype.forEach);

const hookUpClass = className => {
    forEach(document.getElementsByClassName(className), element => {
        new Carousel(element, true, {xs: 6, md: 6, lg: 6 });
    });
};

hookUpClass('slick-media');
hookUpClass('another-class');
hookUpClass('some-further-class');
```

Note the use of `Array.prototype.forEach` to do the looping for us, since it'll work on any array-like thing. That will work on any modern browser and IE9-IE11.

If you don't mind a *very very very very* small bit of overhead, you can use `querySelectorAll` (which exists even on IE8) to get a list matching all of your classes, rather than having to handle each class separately:

```
import Carousel from '../app/assets/javascripts/carousel/Carousel';

document.querySelectorAll('.slick-media, .another-class, .some-further-class').forEach(element => {
    new Carousel(element, true, {xs: 6, md: 6, lg: 6 });
});
```

I didn't use `Array.prototype.forEach` there because `NodeList` has its own `forEach` which does the same thing. If you need to support IE9-IE11, you'll want the polyfill, which is trivial:

```
if (typeof NodeList !== "undefined" &&
    NodeList.prototype &&
    !NodeList.prototype.forEach) {
    // Surprisingly, the standard `NodeList.prototype.forEach` is enumerable (as well as
    // writable and configurable) so we can just assign rather than using `defineProperty`
    NodeList.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
}
```

Or of course, use `Array.prototype.forEach` instead as we did with `getElementsByClassName` if you prefer.

In cutting-edge environments like the latest Chrome and Firefox, you could do this:

```
import Carousel from '../app/assets/javascripts/carousel/Carousel';

for (const element of document.querySelectorAll('.slick-media, .another-class, .some-further-class')) {
    new Carousel(element, true, {xs: 6, md: 6, lg: 6 });
}
```

...which relies on the `NodeList` being *iterable*. I didn't do that above because polyfilling an iterator on `NodeList` is harder than polyfilling `forEach` without knowing what transpiler you're using (if you're using one).

Comment: Brilliant - thank you so much for the details reply, much appreciated!

Comment: @Liondedan - Glad that helped!

Answer (score 2):

Using a class for this seems overkill to me. You are never accessing the created objects later, as you don't you keep a reference to them, so their sole purpose seems to be to perform one immediate action: apply `slick` to elements with some predefined configuration. After their construction they immediately become useless.

Secondly, using a default value for a parameter is not very useful when *after* that you still have a parameter that turns out to be mandatory. So swap the parameter positions of `breakpoint` and `variableWidth`.

As an alternative I would suggest creating a jQuery plug-in for this:

```
$.fn.simpleSlick = function (breakpoint, variableWidth = false) {
    this.slick({
        lazyLoad: 'ondemand',
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        adaptiveHeight: true,
        useTransform: true,
        /* Default over lg breakpoint */
        slidesToShow: breakpoint.lg,
        /* Allow slick to calculate widths */
        variableWidth,
        responsive: [{
            breakpoint: 1199,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: breakpoint.lg,
                slidesToScroll: 1,
                infinite: true
            }
        }, {
            breakpoint: 991,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: breakpoint.md,
                slidesToScroll: 1,
                infinite: true
            }
        }, {
            breakpoint: 480,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: breakpoint.xs,
                slidesToScroll: 1,
                infinite: true
            }
        }]
   });
   return this; // to allow chaining
};
```

And assuming that the `slick` plugin plays according to the rules (i.e. allows the jQuery object to match more than one element), your actual use of it becomes as easy as:

```
$('.slick-media').simpleSlick({xs: 6, md: 6, lg: 6 }, true);
```

#### When the class is a given

If the use of a class should be taken as a given, then you could still use the jQuery way for selecting the elements by their `class` attribute (since you already use jQuery for the `slick` plugin):

```
$('.slick-media').each(function () { 
    new Carousel(this, true, {xs: 6, md: 6, lg: 6 });
});
```

(But again, applying `new` without using the resulting object reveals a wrong design)

And if you want to access these Carousel objects later via the DOM element, then you could consider using the `data` method:

```
$('.slick-media').each(function () { 
    $(this).data('carousel', new Carousel(this, true, {xs: 6, md: 6, lg: 6 }));
});
```

For a given `elem` element, you can then access the corresponding `Carousel` instance as follows:

```
var carousel = $(elem).data('carousel'); // Get the Carousel instance
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @trincot. I agree, in this specific instance, it isn't necessary. I was trying to provide an easy example so I could get an idea of a pattern to follow in this project.

Comment: Are you saying this does not work in your case? If so, could you be so kind to update your question and provide an example that is representative? That way I might be able to provide an answer better tailored to your actual needs.

Comment: Whether one should make a jQuery plugin from it is another question, but yes it definitely should be a standalone function/method that is called once and not a `class` constructor

Answer (score 1):

You can actually shortify it to:

```
 Array.from(
  document.getElementsByClassName('slick-media'), 
  node => new Carousel(node, true, {xs: 6, md: 6, lg: 6 })
);
```

Comment: "shorten" ;-)  This also puts the Carousel objects into the resulting array, which is not the case in OP's code.

Comment: There's no purpose served by using `Array.from` here. As with the OP's use of `map`, it's just needless overhead. (It's also not clear the OP is asking about that code vs. the class itself.)

Comment: Looking from different perspectives here, but yes it is either useful if the result is *used*, or not.

Comment: @t.j.crowder its browser support is better than `NodeList.forEach` i guess... And its more beautiful than a for loop.

Comment: @JonasW., think of `for (const node of document.getElementsByClassName('slick-media')) { ... } `

Comment: @JonasW. Yup! The WebIDL spec now says that _any_ array-like API (length and numeric keys), is supposed to be iterable automatically https://www.w3.org/TR/WebIDL-1/#es-iterator or they can explicitly opt in with an `Iterable<T>` declaration in their type to also get `.forEach`, `.values`, `.keys`, and `.entries`.

Comment: @JonasW.: *"its browser support is better than NodeList.forEach i guess"* Why would you guess that? `Array.from` is quite new too. But `NodeList#forEach` is trivial to polyfill, or just use any of [several other ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476) to loop array-like objects.